# Flutter android error: type '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'double' as cast

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-android

This information might be useful for those who are developing for Web and need to deploy for Android devices.

By handling `double` data type from a json model, I was experiencing the follow error in a flutter app running on real Android phone (not any emulator):

> type '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'double' as cast

This error did not happen for Web version and I did not try for IOS (because, I do not have any IOS device). Also, I did not perform tests on any emulators.

Here is my model:

```
class ModelExample {
  int id;
  String name;
  double percentRank;
  ModelExample({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.percentRank,
  });

  factory ModelExample.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ModelExample(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      name: json['api_name'] as String,
      percentRank: json['api_percent_rank'] as double,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id.toString(),
        'api_name': name,
        'api_percent_rank': percentRank.toString(),
      };

}
```

My environment is:

- Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale en-US)
- Dart version 2.12.3
- Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
- Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
- Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

How can I get rid this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

A way to solve this issue is as follows:

By changing your model `fromJson` method (excerpt) from:

```
factory ModelExample.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    
      ...
    
        percentRank: json['api_percent_rank'] as double,
    
      ...
    
    }
```

to:

```
factory ModelExample.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

  ...

    percentRank: double.parse(json['api_percent_rank'].toString()),

  ...

}
```

After changed that line, that error will go away.

To know better, have a look at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html